# For Loop in Python not seperating list into subsets correctly

Tags: python, list, loops, pycharm

new to Python so bare with.

I am trying to find a way to find whether a list with strings and variables concatenated, is a subset of another list. See code and results so far below

```
y = ['test_sam_20190624.csv', 'test_phil_20190624.csv', 'test_bill_20190624.csv', 'test_jess_20190624.csv', 'test_issy_20190624.csv', 'test_clinton_20190624.csv']
x = ['sam', 'jack', 'bill', 'rodry', 'clinton']
print('\nFile list is ')
print(*y, sep="\n")
print('\nNeeded names are ')
print(*x, sep="\n")

datetoday = '20190624'

incl = [p for p in x if 'test'+p+datetoday+'.csv' in y]
not_incl = [p for p in x if 'test'+p+datetoday+'.csv' not in y]

print("\n Included")
print(*incl, sep="\m")
print("\n Not included")
print(*not_incl, sep="\n")
```

And the output given below:

```
File list is 
test_sam_20190624.csv
test_phil_20190624.csv
test_bill_20190624.csv
test_jess_20190624.csv
test_issy_20190624.csv
test_clinton__20190624.csv

Needed names are 
sam
jack
bill
rodry
clinton

 Included


 Not included
sam
jack
bill
rodry
clinton

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But I would expect `incl = ['sam' 'bill 'clinton']` as an output surely? And the outputs to be:

```
 Included
sam
bill
clinton


 Not included
jack
rodry
```

Where am I going wrong? Maybe in the concatenation of the strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't inlcuding the full string in your search:

```
incl = [p for p in x if 'test'+'_'+p+'_'+datetoday+'.csv' in y]
not_incl = [p for p in x if 'test'+'_'+p+'_'+datetoday+'.csv' not in y]
```

You forgot the underscores in the lookup.

```
[dkennetz@nodecn203  fun]$ python3.5 fun.py

File list is
test_sam_20190624.csv
test_phil_20190624.csv
test_bill_20190624.csv
test_jess_20190624.csv
test_issy_20190624.csv
test_clinton_20190624.csv

Needed names are
sam
jack
bill
rodry
clinton

 Included
sam\mbill\mclinton

 Not included
jack
rodry
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you forgot the `_`s in your concatenation.

Try to change:

```
incl = [p for p in x if 'test'+p+datetoday+'.csv' in y]
```

to

```
incl = [p for p in x if 'test_'+p+'_'+datetoday+'.csv']
```

Same for not_incl:

```
not_incl = [p for p in x if 'test'+p+datetoday+'.csv' not in y]
```

should be

```
not_incl = [p for p in x if 'test_'+p+'_'+datetoday+'.csv' not in y]
```

Now you should get the wanted output.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing underscore (_) in if statement. It should be as follows.

```
incl = [p for p in x if 'test_'+p+'_'+datetoday+'.csv' in y]
not_incl = [p for p in x if 'test_'+p+'_'+datetoday+'.csv' not in y]
```

Answer (score 1):

As all the previous ansers suggest, what is missing is the underscores (_) in the strings.If we take these underscores out, it will not fetch the correct string.

```
incl = [p for p in x if 'test_'+p+'_'+datetoday+'.csv' in y]
not_incl = [p for p in x if 'test_'+p+'_'+datetoday+'.csv' not in y]
```